# LastFM no longer free?

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee, spotify

LastFM used to allow listening *without a subscription* within Rhythmbox (and still does in Ubuntu 10.10), their website suggests this still ought to be the case (at least for those of us in the UK, US or Germany), but as of 11.04 it doesn't work OOTB (neither with Banshee or Rythmbox).

How can I get LastFM working again (without a subscription)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the website](http://blog.last.fm/2011/02/07/lastfm-radio-becomes-a-premium-feature-on-mobile-and-home-entertainment-devices)

> Last.fm Radio will remain free on the Last.fm website in the US, UK and Germany and for the US and UK users of Xbox Live and Windows Mobile 7 phones. We’ll also continue to offer radio for free via the Last.fm desktop app.

Roughly translated it means you can only listen to last.fm by either going to [their website](http://last.fm/radio), using their official desktop client, or becoming a subscriber (which will allow you to use third party apps and on mobile phones). The desktop client is available in the Software Center for free (Screenshot below). Just search for "last.fm"

[image: last.fm desktop client]

Some programs still use last.fm's old API, which allowed anyone to listen to it anywhere.

Comment: Even their desktop app doesn't support playing radios outside US/UK/Germany without a subscription

Comment: In which case you have to get a subscription. It's unfortunate but they explained that it's not profitable for them to operate in other countries, hence the requirement for people to pay http://blog.last.fm/2009/03/24/lastfm-radio-announcement

Comment: They are discriminating music lovers on based of location. Whatever reasons they might have, its not a good thing. Either just switch to free or paid for everyone but no they got a business to run and will make certain users pay, not everyone.

Comment: I think your complaints are best directed at last.fm http://www.last.fm/about/contact

Comment: I am not complaining to you, just putting up my point forward. I will pay & use it when I can't use it for free but its totally uncool.

Comment: OMG It say for me: Just a reminder, your free trial of Last.fm Radio will end after you’ve played 30 tracks. Enjoying it? Subscribe for only €3.00/month. Thats discrimination!!

Comment: Thanks! The desktop client works, though it's a bit buggy with Unity, hopefully (sound) indicators will be supported by 11.10.

Answer (score 0):

It used to work fine for me in Rhythmbox in the last version we might have seen in 10.10
Now I use Fire.fm addon for firefox to play radios.

Its totally dependent on client how they are handling the APIs (Lame Last.fm devs). I have two versions of mobbler on my cell phone. The latest one can't play radios while the earlier one can. so just find something which is based on the old API.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small comment; [Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/) could maybe be an alternative for you.

Comment: Can I use Grooveshark with Banshee such that it plays nice with the sound indicators (display and skip tracks)?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sorry about that.